# Can't get Oracle SQL Developer to display specific values from object table

Tags: oracle, object, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've started learning SQL and playing with Oracle SQL Developer v22. For some reason I'm not able to retrieve value from an object table by using SELECT VALUE(A). It only gives my user ID.object_name as in the below screenshot. Any tips why?

[SELECT VALUE(A) FROM table A;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTITp.png)

If I use SELECT * FROM table; all is fine.
[SELECT * FROM table A;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA3ja.png)

I've tried printing using dmbs_output, same problem.
Tried with other object tables, same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share your table DDL and DML for a more accurate answer, but setting this preference should do what you're looking for

'Display Struct Value in Grid'

[image]

[I talk about that here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/01/oracle-sql-developer-display-structured-value-in-grid/)

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am the product manager for SQL Developer.*

Comment: Amazing, that resolved it right away, thank you so much!
By now I thought I had read the whole internet to no avail, and turns out it's a setting, who knew... Marked your article as well